# Thought experiment about fluid mechanics (reductio ad absurdum)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, perpetual-motion

In an interview a philosopher said:

"Suppose I cut the handle off your coffee mug leaving two holes. Would the coffee flow out of one hole faster than the other? If we tried to figure this out by experiment, we would need to carefully measure the flow – and we would ruin your mug. We should instead mentally replace the handle with a tube. If the flow of one hole exceeded the other, we would have a perpetual motion machine. Since that is absurd, we can deduce that the holes have the same rate of flow."

Is this true? Why wouldn't the lower hole have a higher rate of flow? Isn't there a higher pressure?

Comment: I don't think that the situation with holes is exactly the same as the one with the tube. Think of the pressures at the interfaces for instance...

Comment: Just to split hairs - a perpetual motion _machine_ is one that produces an output of work/energy. Anything can move indefinitely in the absence of external forces. The _doing work_ part of the definition of a machine is what makes a PMM impossible.

Comment: I think the philosopher has got the wrong idea about PMM. Isnt the differing pressure the basic idea of Hydel Power.

Comment: Never trust what a philosopher says about physics. For that matter, you shouldn't even trust whether a philosopher to get your order right when he asks whether you want fries with the hamburger you just ordered.

Comment: Ignoring lesser effects, the flow rate out of a hole is proportional to the square root of the depth of the hole.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument is wrong. The flow rate that is observed when the hole is freely communicating with the atmosphere is not the same flow rate that will be observed when the two holes are connected with a tube.

The reason is that the flow rate through a hole depends on the pressure differential across the hole - on one side there is a certain height of liquid providing pressure, and on the other side (for the first case) there is just atmospheric pressure. So when you make two holes in your mug, the lower hole will have the faster flow rate. Formally this can be analyzed with Bernoulli's equation, but when you are talking to a philosopher you may want a simpler argument.

Imagine a particle of water starting to "fall" from the top of the surface of the water (since the surface of the water is lowering, you can think of the potential energy lost by the water being equal to energy lost by moving water from the surface to the exit hole - it's not actually the same particle, but as water disappears from the surface it re-appears at the hole). Now that particle (mass $m$) lost potential energy $mgh$. converting that to kinetic energy, it's going to flow at a velocity $v$ such that $\frac12 mv^2 = mgh$, or $v\propto \sqrt{h}$.

When the two are connected with a tube, there is equal pressure on both sides and no flow at all.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, there is equal pressure on both sides **of each hole** when the tube is considered. The pressure at the interface of both holes is different in general as I'd expect the two holes to be at different heights.

Comment: @Phoenix87 changed wording slightly. Better?